# Android 4.4: get lastmodified date

Tags: android

I need find out last modified time of file on web.
I try this, but didnt work. My aplication crash, but in java project it runs good. Can you help me ?

```
URL webUrl = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) webUrl.openConnection();
long date = httpCon.getLastModified();
```

i try this, but same result

```
long date = httpCon.getHeaderFieldDate("Last-Modified", 0);
```

Comment: Your application is probably crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. If so, read for example http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask

Comment: "My aplication crash" -- use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.